# extract binary data and convert them following a specific alphabet

Tags: python, binary, comparison

I need to extract a few bytes from a binary file. Every single byte represents an alphabet character coded in a specific way. So i was thinking of extracting the bytes and then compare them one by one with an array containing the complete alphabet.

Im using

```
byte = filename.read(1)
byte = binascii.hexlify(byte)
```

to read a single byte from the file, but i dont understand how it's possible to stop reading when i find the termination hex value 0x50.

(i started learning python just today)

thanks in advance

PS: this is the complete code i tried

```
byte = filename.read(1)
byte = binascii.hexlify(byte)

while byte !=0x50:
    tempName.append(byte)
    byte = filename.read(1)
    byte = binascii.hexlify(byte)
```

and it doesnt work, it enters an endless loop

Comment: Show us what you've tried.  How about a `while` loop while `byte != 0x50`?

Comment: yes i tried that, i've just added a more complete versione of the code

Comment: Hint: `hexlify` returns a string, so comparing it with an integer (like `0x50`) will always evaluate to `False`

Comment: mmm ok thank you, but is there a way to obtain an actual hex value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare the integer `0x50` with the string returned by `hexlify`. `byte != 0x50` will always evaluate to true.

Use `ord` to find the numerical value of a character. Sample usage:

```
file = open("input.txt", "rb")

bytes = []
while True:
    byte = file.read(1)
    print byte
    bytes.append(byte)
    if ord(byte) == 0x50:
        break

print bytes
```

Contents of `input.txt`:

```
Hello, world!P Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

(note that capital P has numerical value 0x50)

Output:

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!', 'P']
```

Comment: thank you very much! i finally understood your code :D...thanks for your help